# Filter to prevent controller constructor or Initialize from executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assume this ActionFilter:

```
public class MemberAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["someValue"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Error");
        }

    }
}
```

And assume this base controller:

```
[Member]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected int _memberID;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        _memberID = int.Parse(requestContext.HttpContext.Session["someValue"].ToString());
    }

}
```

In a controller that extends BaseController I have this action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PlayerCreateVM vm)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        vm.Player.MemberID = _memberID;
        _playerManager.Create(vm.Player.ToModel());

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

As you can see in the action the creation of a 'player' in this case relies on _memberID not being null. Hence the ActionFilter that is applied to the BaseController. None of the actions in the sub classed Controllers will fire unless this value is not null.

But, the BaseControllers Initialize() and the BaseController's constructor still fire. Is there an equivelant type of Filter that actually prevents the constructor and its base from even being constructed.

Comment: Short answer is no - the `OnActionExecuting` cannot execute until the class has been initialized. But why not just check for `null` in the constructor? And it seems odd that you would redirect the user to an error page because it is `null` (the value could be `null` for many reasons including that `Session` has expired or been recycled, so you should be fixing that-  e.g. get the value again and add it to `Session` -  rather than telling the user there is an error)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke .. its a contrived example of a real world scenario. The short answer was useful though :)